# Vlookup Based On 2 Columns - Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, concatenation, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, gs-vlookup

I'm consolidating two sheets that are populated via two separate google forms. I'm trying to find a row where 2 column items match to return a different cell via vlookup.

**Example:** I need to get value in `'NAMES SHEET'!C4` to appear in `'SHOPS SHEET'!C3`.

I'm trying to match both the DATE and SHOP columns - but have had no luck.

I've tried using `'NAMES SHEET'!A4&'NAMES SHEET'!B4` as my search parameters, but it concats the two cells together. I've been stuck at this a while- any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

use in **'SHOPS SHEET'!C3**:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFNA(VLOOKUP(A3:A&B3:B, 
 {'NAMES SHEET'!A3:A&'NAMES SHEET'!B3:B, 'NAMES SHEET'!C3:C}, 2, 0)))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`FILTER`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093197?hl=en) in `'SHOPS SHEET'!C3`:

```
=IFNA(FILTER('NAMES SHEET'!C3:C, 'NAMES SHEET'!A3:A = A3:A, 'NAMES SHEET'!B3:B = B3:B))
```

Not you case probably, but if there are data like this in `NAMES SHEET` there will be a problem with `VLOOKUP` using concatenated columns:

[image]

Comment: problem solved: `=ARRAYFORMULA(IFNA(VLOOKUP(A3:A&" "&B3:B, 
 {'NAMES SHEET'!A3:A&" "&'NAMES SHEET'!B3:B, 'NAMES SHEET'!C3:C}, 2, 0)))`

Comment: @player0 there is no universal separator: [demo](https://i.imgur.com/o5BhHqh.png). Either some restrictions should be forced on or just do not use concatenation before comparing.

Comment: Sure, but then those should not be in any cell - that's the restriction I'm talking about.